# Video file from chrome cache

Tags: google-chrome, video, browser-cache

I have a file with no extension taken from Chrome's cache, I know it's a video but it does not play with any players. I tried the suggestions from similar questions here. Is there anything I could try apart from what has been said?

Comment: How do you know its a video file ?

Answer (score 1):

you can try to use [VideoCacheView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/video_cache_view.html)
from nirsoft if u haven't already.

> Description
>
> After watching a video in a Web site, you may want to save the video
>   file into your local disk for playing it offline in the future. If the
>   video file is stored in your browser's cache, this utility can help
>   you to extract the video file from the cache and save it for watching
>   it in the future.

Answer (score 0):

> does not play with any players

Including Videolan VLC ?

Does Mediainfo not reveal anything about it either ?

Open the file in an editor like Notepad++ - do the first dozen or so 
bytes look like it might even be a video file ?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [TrIDNet - File Identifier](http://mark0.net/soft-tridnet-e.html) to see what kind of file it is. That way you'd know for sure if it's a video file or not.

Other than that, philx's answer is also worth trying.

Answer (score -1):

I`m not gonna write all details, but... Try to change file extension to .avi or other video format. Done it ages ago, but only after changing extension to video format other programs should be able to read it.

Comment: Please elaborate your response - the whole point of this site is to provide details.